# Get latest record from a shared table with Spring Boo JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have this application with a CRUD for servers and systems and along with it a service that checks the status of this servers and systems and persists the results in my monitoring table, using the enum elementType to differentiate between elements in case the same id happens.

Now when I retrieve a server or system by their respective repositories, I want it to come with the latest monitoring, but the attribute latestMonitoring keeps returning null with no error output to guide me, I need some help.

```
public class Server {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    private StatusEnum status;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SERVER_ID")
    @Where(clause = "status<>'DISABLED'")
    private List<System> systems;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MONITORED")
    @Where(clause = "elementType='SERVER' AND date= (SELECT MAX(date) FROM Monitoring)")
    private Monitoring latestMonitoring;
}

public class System{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    private StatusEnum status;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MONITORED")
    @Where(clause = "elementType='SYSTEM' AND date= (SELECT MAX(date) FROM Monitoring)")
    private Monitoring latestMonitoring;
}

public class Monitoring {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ID_MONITORED", nullable = false)
    private Long idMonitored;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "TYPE", nullable = false)
    private MonitoringEnum elementType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS_BEFORE", nullable = false)
    private StatusEnum statusBefore;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS_NOW", nullable = false)
    private StatusEnum statusNow;

    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

Comment: from `...clause = "elementType='SYSTEM' AND date= (SELECT MAX(date)...`, _date_ is not a valid `Monitoring` field.  (I'm somewhat surprised that would even compile or at least the app not start up.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that @AndrewS ,it was my mistake here, not in the application

Comment: What is the SQL issued from fetching System/Server and their latestMonitoring property? What are the results if you run the query yourself? How have you created the System and Server instances you are reading back - could they have been cached incompletely with latestMonitoring set to null? Note that latestMonitoring isn't constantly polled from the DB, so if it has changed since the last time the holding entity was read, it won't be reflected in the entity.